# Create a folder in SQL Server 2008 like 'system databases'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, how do I create a folder in my 'databases' folder similiar to 'system databases'.

It would be a great way to group like db's.

Comment: Sounds Like "Object Explorer" to me...

Comment: No, you cannot modify the "Object Explorer" window - there's no way to create folders in there, sorry. There's no way to group your databases other than giving them meaningful names....

Comment: If only this were possible :(

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is 100% possible using a SQL Handy Groupie add-in for SSMS. Head on to http://www.skilledsoftware.com for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be one of the first to buy the plugin that made this possible, but for the mean time we stick to naming conventions to group like databases, tables, views and stored procedures together.